# Best practice to add polymorphic attachments to a post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to figure out how to solve following problem:

I have a model called **Post** that has, among other attributes, `link_1_text`, `link_1_url`, `link_2_text` and `link_2_url` for users to add links to their posts and label them like:

- 'Find us here' / 'maps.google.com/something'
- 'Our Facebook' / 'facebook.com/example.com'

So what we want now is to have, instead of the `link_X_url`:

- a PDF document (uploaded)
- a photo gallery (uploaded)
- show a form (static html)
- a youtube link

etc.

My first idea was this, but I'm not happy with it:

**PostAttachment**: `id`, `post_id`, `attachment_type`, `title`, `text`, `url`, `document`

*attachment_types*: [`link`, `pdf`, `form`, `text`, `youtube`]

which will then work like:

- **link**: Render `url` (same as now)
- **pdf**: Render `document`
- **form**: Render static html file
- **text**: Render `text`
- **youtube**: Render `url` in an iframe

Which is everything but a neat approach to this, so: how can I keep it as generic as possible but yet nice + clean codewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most robust way:

```rb
module Attachment
  class Base
    class << self
      attr_reader :media_type

      # I'm using JSON here, but you can use any string format, e.g. YAML
      # String -> Obj
      def load(json_str)
        return if json_str.nil?
        json = JSON.parse(json_str, symbolize_names: true) rescue return
        media_type = json[:media_type]
        subclasses.fetch(media_type, Base).new(json[:data])
      end

      # Obj -> String
      def dump(obj)
        wrong_type_msg = "Attribute was supposed to be a #{self}, but was a #{obj.class}. -- #{obj.inspect}"
        raise ::ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch, wrong_type_msg unless obj.is_a?(self)
        obj.as_json.to_json
      end

      protected

      def set_media_type(media_type)
        @media_type = media_type
        subclasses[@media_type] = self
      end

      private

      def subclasses
        @@subclasses ||= {}
      end
    end

    def initialize(data)
      @data = data.to_s
    end

    # redefine for subclasses to return everything a view needs to render
    def render
      "Sorry, not able to render"
    end

    def ==(other)
      self.class == other.class &&
        as_json == other.as_json
    end
    delegate :eql?, to: :==

    def hash
      self.class.hash ^ as_json.hash
    end

    def as_json
      { media_type: self.class.media_type, data: @data }
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :attachment, Attachment::Base, # tells AR to use `.load` and `.dump`
end
```

```rb
module Attachment
  # Make as many polymorphic specializations of Base as you need

  class Url < Base
    set_media_type name.underscore
  end

  class Pdf < Base
    set_media_type 'application/pdf'
  end

  class Html < Base
    set_media_type 'text/html'
  end

  class Text < Base
    set_media_type name.underscore
  end

  class Youtube < Base
    set_media_type name.underscore
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
post = Post.first
post.attachment = Attachment::Youtube.new('asdfasdf')
# => #<Attachment::Youtube:0x00007fef6cfd91d0 @data="asdfasdf">
post.save

Post.first.attachment # query fresh from db
# => #<Attachment::Youtube:0x00007fef6a4cd6d0 @data="asdfasdf">
```

Maintain [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) of the classes. `Attachment::Base` should always be a safe fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Define a struct with two fields, a blob for the data, and a internet-media-type.

```
arg = Struct.new(:data, :media_type)
```

Use media types from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: I'm not sure if saving whole PDF documents and dozens of images of a photo gallery in a database is a good idea? I'd rather keep the files in a filesystem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with storing data in a database.  Or using the filesystem as a database.  But my suggestion had little to do with longterm storage. It was about how to encapsulate the data in a way that met the questioners extensabilty needs

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to figure out how to properly save it but your suggestions pointed me to a good direction - thanks!